# how do you render a js.erb file with a link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

Let's say you have a link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Add Topics", ???, :remote => true, :id => 'edit_topics_link' %>
```

What do you put where the ??? is to render a js.erb file in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an action in your controller which responds_to with `format.js` and the route for it.

```
def action
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

the in routes

```
resources :something do
  member do
    get or post :action, :as => :blah
  end
end
```

Then if you run `rake routes` you will see something like `blah_something_path` which you can use in `link_to`